# Possible to use SVG markup with a force in D3?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm having some issues getting my SVG markup to play well with different forces specifically when I fire the 'tick' callback. I'm attempting to update the element's `cx` and `cy` properties while the simulation is running, but they don't inherently have a property I can update. For example:

```
var shape = d3.selectAll('circle')
.on('mouseenter', handleCircleMouseEnter)
.on('mouseout', handleCircleMouseOut)
.on('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
.attr('cursor', 'pointer')
.attr('class', 'shapes')
.attr('cx', function(d) {return d.x;})
.attr('cy', function(d) {return d.y;})

var shapes = d3.selectAll('.shapes')

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(shapes)

simulation
    .force('charge_force', d3.forceManyBody())
    .force('charge', d3.forceCollide().radius(5))
    .force('center_force', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .on('tick', ticked)

function ticked() {
    // always returns with 'd' as undefined
    shapes.attr('cx', function(d) {return d.x;})
    shapes.attr('cy', function(d) {return d.y;})
}
```

What's strange is if I return nothing on either of the 'tick' attributes, I get movement with my force, but `d` never gets passed in.

The one strange thing I'm doing is I'm never building this SVG with D3, I have an SVG element in markup that I'm modifying with a force. Not sure this is possible, but it seems like it's almost working. At a loss...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (I'm curious to hearing from you if I did) you want to use a force simulation with elements already present in the SVG. If that's the case, the answer is **yes**. But there is a catch:

The force simulation uses an array of objects to set the relevant properties. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_nodes):

> simulation.nodes([nodes]) <>
>
> If nodes is specified, sets the simulation’s nodes to the specified **array of objects**, initializing their positions and velocities if necessary, and then re-initializes any bound forces. (emphasis mine)

That array of objects is simply the **data** bound to them. However, as you're getting the elements already present in the SVG there is no data bound (unless we bind them manually, keep reading...), and that explains why `d` returns `undefined`.

So, we'll have to bind data to the elements. Let's see how this can be done. Suppose this SVG, with 3 circles already present:

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="20" cy="75" r="20" fill="green"></circle>
  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
  <circle cx="280" cy="75" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
</svg>
```

To use the force simulation, we'll first set the datum of each circle:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle");
circles.each(function() {
  d3.select(this).datum({
    x: +d3.select(this).attr("cx"),
    y: +d3.select(this).attr("cy")
  })
});
```

It can be any object, even this will work:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle");
circles.each(function() {
  d3.select(this).datum({foo: "bar"})
});
```

Then, we pass that array of objects to the simulation:

```
var data = circles.data()
simulation.nodes(data)
  .on("tick", ticked);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(20))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(+100))
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle");
circles.each(function() {
  d3.select(this).datum({
    x: +d3.select(this).attr("cx"),
    y: +d3.select(this).attr("cy")
  })
});
var data = circles.data()
simulation.nodes(data)
  .on("tick", ticked);

function ticked() {
  circles.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="20" cy="75" r="20" fill="green"></circle>
  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
  <circle cx="280" cy="75" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer, I dipped into the D3 Slack channel and you definitely got what I was after. The piece I was missing was the `datum` setup you mention here. I set up a range of blank JS objects and that seemed to get things up and running, but I'll have a shot with some of the techniques you mention here.  

THANK YOU for the input, pretty experienced with JS, but very green with D3. Seeing that the data property was required in order to iterate properly was a pitfall.

Comment: Good to know, I was not quite sure if that was your question.

Comment: D3 definitely take some getting used to, but I can see what everyone likes about it. The changes from v3-v4 threw for a loop. Makes far more sense now, thanks again!

Comment: Actually @Gerardo, if I was to use two separate shapes (circles and rects for example) in your above demo, would I make two different `data` objects and combine the two arrays into one _before_ handing it to the simulation?

Comment: I was about to reply your comment but, when I stopped to think, I came to the conclusion that this is a very interesting question... can you post it as a *new* question, with all the relevant details? (you can link this one for context) If you do that I will write an answer but I'm asking this because I'm interested in other user's answers, there may be more than one solution here.